# Redirect after login for multiple roles in Laravel

Tags: laravel, redirect, authentication, roles

I'm trying to redirect to specific pages after login. I have this code in my LoginController file, inside of the class LoginController

```
public function authenticated($request , $user){
    if($user->rol=='Administrador'){
        return redirect()->route('home') ;
    }elseif($user->rol=='Docente'){
        return redirect()->route('balance') ;
    }else {
        return redirect()->route('profile');
    }

}
```

Also I have put the route in my web.php file

The problem comes when i'm trying to see if this function worked, because when I introduce a alumno user it should redirect to **profile**, but it doesn't

Comment: Laravel middlewares does the job you are trying to achieve here. Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware#middleware-parameters

Comment: when your role is `alumno`, where it redirected?

Comment: it redirects to /home

Comment: Are you using the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait in your `LoginController` class?

Answer (score 2):

In `LoginController.php` file (which is generated when you `run php artisan make:auth`), there is a property that handles it.

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Remove this property, and add a method with equal name.

```
public function redirectTo(){
    // Code here
}
```

The redirectTo method will take precedence over the redirectTo property. This allows us to define logic to handle users with different role to different paths.

```
public function redirectTo(){

    // User role
    $role = Auth::user()->role->name; 

    // Check user role
    switch ($role) {
        case 'Manager':
                return '/dashboard';
            break;
        case 'Employee':
                return '/projects';
            break; 
        default:
                return '/login'; 
            break;
    }
}
```

Source: [Learn how to redirect authenticated users to corresponding path in Laravel](https://codeburst.io/learn-how-to-redirect-authenticated-users-to-corresponding-path-in-laravel-dd613e2f9e3)

Comment: The `LoginController` class could have been overridden. This answer is valid (and the best IMHO) only if @Anais uses the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait in the `LoginController` class.

Comment: Yeah i'm using this class in my LoginController file, what I'm seeing is that Is not working because the role of the user is not on the same table *User*

Comment: Okay then you could adjust the definition of `$role`. Maybe something like the following `$role = Auth::user()->relationship->column;`

Answer (score 1):

Try to Use `switch` statement

```
public function authenticated($request , $user){
  switch ($user->rol){
    case 'Administrador':
      return redirect()->route('home') ;
    case 'Docente':
      return redirect()->route('balance') ;
    default:
      return redirect()->route('profile') ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Put this in `LoginController` file, in your `authenticated` function

Comment: and that's it? I don't have to put nothing in the routes file

Comment: No, I have this Route::get('/profile', 'Auth\LoginController@authenticated')->name('profile'); because if i dont an error appears

Comment: try to `dd($user->rol)` under `public function authenticated($request , $user)` and see what response